# child_process.spawnSync error 'ENOENT' when unzipping a file

Tags: node.js, zip, command-line-interface, child-process, unzip

I'm trying to execute a cli command using `child_process.spawnSync` to unzip a file, but when I run the code it says `ENOENT` even though the command works fine.

```
const result = spawnSync(`unzip ${path}`, [
  passwordArg,  // ''
  outputArg,  // ''
]);
```

```
// console.log(result)
error: Error: spawnSync unzip /<...>/unzipFiles/test/zipp.zip ENOENT

...

errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawnSync unzip /<...>/unzipFiles/test/zipp.zip',
  path: 'unzip /<...>/unzipFiles/test/zipp.zip',
  spawnargs: ['', '']
```

If I copy and paste and execute the exact value for `path`, i.e. `unzip /<...>/unzipFiles/test/zipp.zip`, it runs as expected.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `spawnSync` is executed in the directory where you started the Node.js process. If you don't want that, set the option `spawnSync("command", [args], {cwd: "<directory>"})`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That doesn't explain the error message, however.